# Arch can't connect to specific wireless network

Tags: wifi

I am using a [TP-Link AV-500](http://www.tp-link.com/en/products/details/cat-18_TL-PA4010KIT.html) power line adapter kit to provide a wireless AP in a part of my house. It connects though the power lines to my main router. My laptop, however, which is running 64bit Arch Linux, can't connect to it.

Other devices (an Android phone, an iPhone, an Android tablet) can connect with no problem. The laptop can connect to the router and other access points perfectly well (including a 5Ghz network), but although it sees the TP-Link access point, it cannot connect to it. Here's the relevant section from `dmesg`:

```
[  112.910085] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp3s0b1: link is not ready
[  113.033293] brcmsmac bcma0:1: brcms_ops_bss_info_changed: qos enabled: false (implement)
[  113.033308] brcmsmac bcma0:1: brcms_ops_config: change power-save mode: false (implement)
[  113.034398] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp3s0b1: link is not ready
[  116.580167] wlp3s0b1: authenticate with ec:08:6b:ac:79:32
[  116.584039] wlp3s0b1: send auth to ec:08:6b:ac:79:32 (try 1/3)
[  117.485493] wlp3s0b1: send auth to ec:08:6b:ac:79:32 (try 2/3)
[  118.486054] wlp3s0b1: send auth to ec:08:6b:ac:79:32 (try 3/3)
[  119.506587] wlp3s0b1: authentication with ec:08:6b:ac:79:32 timed out
[  124.564520] wlp3s0b1: authenticate with ec:08:6b:ac:79:32
[  124.573264] wlp3s0b1: send auth to ec:08:6b:ac:79:32 (try 1/3)
[  124.573388] wlp3s0b1: send auth to ec:08:6b:ac:79:32 (try 2/3)
[  125.499764] wlp3s0b1: send auth to ec:08:6b:ac:79:32 (try 3/3)
[  126.490269] wlp3s0b1: authentication with ec:08:6b:ac:79:32 timed out
[  131.941087] wlp3s0b1: authenticate with ec:08:6b:ac:79:32
[  131.950493] wlp3s0b1: send auth to ec:08:6b:ac:79:32 (try 1/3)
[  131.952053] wlp3s0b1: send auth to ec:08:6b:ac:79:32 (try 2/3)
[  132.503479] wlp3s0b1: send auth to ec:08:6b:ac:79:32 (try 3/3)
[  133.493991] wlp3s0b1: authentication with ec:08:6b:ac:79:32 timed out
[  138.177601] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp3s0b1: link is not ready
[  138.213885] brcmsmac bcma0:1: brcms_ops_bss_info_changed: qos enabled: false (implement)
[  138.213900] brcmsmac bcma0:1: brcms_ops_config: change power-save mode: false (implement)
```

As soon as that fails, it automatically connects to the main AP provided by the router (which is at the limit of its range):

```
[  138.216719] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp3s0b1: link is not ready
[  141.724430] brcmsmac bcma0:1: brcms_ops_bss_info_changed: qos enabled: false (implement)
[  141.724446] brcmsmac bcma0:1: brcms_ops_config: change power-save mode: false (implement)
[  141.725597] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp3s0b1: link is not ready
[  145.270747] wlp3s0b1: authenticate with 18:a6:f7:93:15:07
[  145.281964] wlp3s0b1: send auth to 18:a6:f7:93:15:07 (try 1/3)
[  145.283393] wlp3s0b1: authenticated
[  145.286615] wlp3s0b1: associate with 18:a6:f7:93:15:07 (try 1/3)
[  145.290540] wlp3s0b1: RX AssocResp from 18:a6:f7:93:15:07 (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=54)
[  145.291094] brcmsmac bcma0:1: brcmsmac: brcms_ops_bss_info_changed: associated
[  145.291099] brcmsmac bcma0:1: brcms_ops_bss_info_changed: qos enabled: true (implement)
[  145.291140] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp3s0b1: link becomes ready
[  145.291523] wlp3s0b1: associated
```

I have disabled security on the TP-Link so it isn't an authentication problem. It is set to "11bgn mixed" mode:

[image: screenshot of AP settings]

My wireless NIC is:

```
$ # lspci -s 03:00.0 -vv
03:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM43224 802.11a/b/g/n (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Dell Wireless 1520 Half-size Mini PCIe Card
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 17
    Region 0: Memory at e6e00000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
        Flags: PMEClk- DSI- D1+ D2+ AuxCurrent=0mA PME(D0+,D1-,D2-,D3hot+,D3cold+)
        Status: D0 NoSoftRst+ PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=2 PME-
    Capabilities: [58] Vendor Specific Information: Len=78 <?>
    Capabilities: [48] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
        Address: 0000000000000000  Data: 0000
    Capabilities: [d0] Express (v1) Endpoint, MSI 00
        DevCap: MaxPayload 128 bytes, PhantFunc 0, Latency L0s <4us, L1 unlimited
            ExtTag+ AttnBtn- AttnInd- PwrInd- RBE+ FLReset- SlotPowerLimit 10.000W
        DevCtl: Report errors: Correctable- Non-Fatal- Fatal- Unsupported-
            RlxdOrd- ExtTag- PhantFunc- AuxPwr- NoSnoop-
            MaxPayload 128 bytes, MaxReadReq 128 bytes
        DevSta: CorrErr+ UncorrErr- FatalErr- UnsuppReq- AuxPwr+ TransPend-
        LnkCap: Port #0, Speed 2.5GT/s, Width x1, ASPM L0s L1, Exit Latency L0s <4us, L1 <64us
            ClockPM+ Surprise- LLActRep+ BwNot- ASPMOptComp-
        LnkCtl: ASPM L0s L1 Enabled; RCB 64 bytes Disabled- CommClk+
            ExtSynch- ClockPM+ AutWidDis- BWInt- AutBWInt-
        LnkSta: Speed 2.5GT/s, Width x1, TrErr- Train- SlotClk+ DLActive+ BWMgmt- ABWMgmt-
    Capabilities: [100 v1] Advanced Error Reporting
        UESta:  DLP- SDES- TLP- FCP- CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF- MalfTLP- ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
        UEMsk:  DLP- SDES- TLP- FCP- CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF- MalfTLP- ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
        UESvrt: DLP+ SDES- TLP- FCP+ CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF+ MalfTLP+ ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
        CESta:  RxErr- BadTLP+ BadDLLP+ Rollover- Timeout- NonFatalErr-
        CEMsk:  RxErr- BadTLP- BadDLLP- Rollover- Timeout- NonFatalErr+
        AERCap: First Error Pointer: 14, GenCap+ CGenEn- ChkCap+ ChkEn-
    Capabilities: [13c v1] Virtual Channel
        Caps:   LPEVC=0 RefClk=100ns PATEntryBits=1
        Arb:    Fixed- WRR32- WRR64- WRR128-
        Ctrl:   ArbSelect=Fixed
        Status: InProgress-
        VC0:    Caps:   PATOffset=00 MaxTimeSlots=1 RejSnoopTrans-
            Arb:    Fixed- WRR32- WRR64- WRR128- TWRR128- WRR256-
            Ctrl:   Enable+ ID=0 ArbSelect=Fixed TC/VC=ff
            Status: NegoPending- InProgress-
    Capabilities: [160 v1] Device Serial Number 00-00-19-ff-ff-5f-c4-46
    Capabilities: [16c v1] Power Budgeting <?>
    Kernel driver in use: bcma-pci-bridge
    Kernel modules: bcma
```

I also tried the `wl` driver:

```
$ sudo modprobe -r brcmsmac 
$ sudo modprobe wl
$ sudo modprobe lib80211
```

That also can't connect but gives a different error:

```
[ 1058.819957] wlan0: Broadcom BCM4353 802.11 Hybrid Wireless Controller 6.30.223.271 (r587334)
[ 1058.822051] wl 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: renamed from wlan0
[ 1058.840226] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp3s0: link is not ready
[ 1060.994623] perf: interrupt took too long (3960 > 3932), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 50400
[ 1061.054105] ERROR @wl_cfg80211_scan : WLC_SCAN error (-22)
[ 1062.055567] ERROR @wl_cfg80211_scan : WLC_SCAN error (-22)
[ 1066.052464] lib80211: common routines for IEEE802.11 drivers
[ 1066.052466] lib80211_crypt: registered algorithm 'NULL'
[ 1076.279617] ERROR @wl_cfg80211_scan : WLC_SCAN error (-22)
[ 1077.281794] ERROR @wl_cfg80211_scan : WLC_SCAN error (-22)
```

Following GAD3R's suggestion, I tried disabling IPv6 by adding `ipv6.disable=1` to the `options` line in `/boot/loader/entries/arch.conf`, commenting out any IPv6 lines from `/etc/hosts` and rebooting. No difference.

How can I connect this machine to this network?

Comment: Did you installed the `broadcom-wl` from AUR?

Comment: @GAD3R I installed the [broadcom-wl-dkms](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/broadcom-wl-dkms/)  one.